# How can i use react slick slider to achieve a grid carousel layout

Tags: reactjs, frontend

[image: Rea]

How can I use a react slick slider to achieve a grid carousel layout? I place a row component within a .map(), this gives me the first desired layout but I can't seem to figure out how to repeat the layout vertically whilst taking into consideration the slide count.

Here's my code for the component; it takes an array of objects then loops through to produce the slide.

```
const RecentJobsSlider = (props) => {
    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    const jobs = props.jobs;

    return (
        <Slider {...settings}>

            {
                jobs.map((job) => (
                    <Row className="center-v entities-grid" between="xs" between="xs">
                        <div className="col-6 entity" key={job.id}>
                            <div className="entity-top">
                                <div className="entity-image">
                                    <img src={job.img}
                                        style={{
                                            width: '50px',
                                            height: '50px',
                                            objectFit: 'contain'
                                        }} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="entity-title" >
                                    <h3>{job.name}</h3>
                                    <p>{job.sector}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p className="entity-desc"> {job.desc} </p>
                            <p className="entity-authors"> <span className="fa fa-map-marker"></span> {job.address} </p>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                )
                )
            }

        </Slider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missed some settings on your slider 
in particular `rows: 3, slidesToShow: 2,`

```
const settings = {
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        rows: 3,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };

<Slider {...settings}>
{ content}
</Slider>
```

Comment: Hello @harisu, thanks so much. You've been a joy for me today. Glad. +1